# Failed to compile resources

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I get this error message when I try to compile for Android in Unity 5.5.0f3 after I've added the play store services package downloaded from the official github repo.

```
Failed to compile resources with the following parameters:
-bootclasspath "C:/Users/Riccardo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar" -d "D:\Develop\Unity Projects\OxS Tennis Game Mobile\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "android\support\v4\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\auth\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\auth\api\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\base\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\drive\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\games\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\nearby\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\tasks\R.java" "com\google\example\games\mainlibproj\R.java" "com\IgnisTenebrisStudio\Hellball\R.java" "com\unity3d\ads\R.java"
warning: C:\Users\Riccardo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar(java/lang/Object.class): major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
warning: C:\Users\Riccardo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar(java/lang/AutoCloseable.class): major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
2 warnings

UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

I also have both JAVA_HOME and Path set (Win 10 os).

JAVA_HOME in my case is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79`

and in Path i have `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin`

Someone can help me?
Should I try to update to jdk1.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution.

I updataed to jdk 1.8_111 and updated all the system paths. Now Unity is compiling my project.